# Replace lines in text file inside tar file with sed and regular expressions

Tags: regex, sed

File `b.txt` in a tar file `b.tar` contains lines such as these:

```
dir1 => /dir1A
dir2 => /dir2A
```

I would like a concise expression for replacing it inside the tar file with a version with these lines instead:

```
dir1 = /dir1B
dir2 = /dir2B
```

The expression may rely on the fact that a copy of `b.txt` exists in the same directory as `a.tar`.

My `sed` skills are a bit rustly. I've tried the following but it does not quite work yet. What is my mistake? Is there an even more concise version?

```
tar df a.tar b.txt
echo b.txt |
  sed \#^dir1[ \t]*=>.*$#dir1 => /dir1B# |
  sed \#^dir2[ \t]*=>.*$#dir2 => /dir2B# |
  tar af a.tar -
```

Comment: so the `tar` file doesn't really enter into your problem, because you have "un"tarred it already? The correct syntax for a substitution in sed is `sed '\#...#...#' file` (note the leading `s` and single-quotes). Also you can combine multiple substitutions in one call  like `sed 's\#...#...#;\#..2..#...#` (note the semicolon separating the commands). Good luck;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (is a bit less concise than I had originally hoped for but) apparently does the trick:

```
TMP_DIR=`mktemp -d`
cat b.txt | \
  sed 's#^\(dir1A\s*=\s*\)\(.*\)\(\s*\)$#\1/dir1B\3#' | \
  sed 's#^\(dir2A\s*=\s*\)\(.*\)\(\s*\)$#\1/dir2B\3#' > \
  $TMP_DIR/b.txt
tar fv a.tar --delete ./b.txt
tar fv a.tar -C $TMP_DIR --append ./b.txt
rm -fr $TMP_DIR
```